# How to display current logged In User in SharePoint Using SPFx?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I am working on a SharePoint Web part using SPF to display welcome a message to current logged in user. I am new to SPF and with little knowledge in JavaScript.

I Have tried this code which displays the list of properties. But i am not sure how to only display the user first name.

```js
private GetUserProperties(): void {
  pnp.sp.profiles.myProperties.get().then(function(result) {
    var userProperties = result.UserProfileProperties;
    var userName = ""; userProperties.forEach(function(property: { Key: 
      string; Value: string; }) {
      userName += property.Key + " - " + property.Value + "<br/>";
    });

    document.getElementById("FirstName").innerHTML = userName;
  })
  .catch(function(error) { console.log("Error: " + error); });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any loading point in a SharePoint Framework app (WebPart, ApplicationCustomizer, ...) you get a context object derived from `BaseComponentContext` as a private member of the class. This object gives you many things, among which you have `context.pageContext.user.` and the following properties:

```json
{
  displayName: string
  email: string
  firstDayOfWeek: undefined
  isAnonymousGuestUser: boolean
  isExternalGuestUser: boolean
  loginName: string
  preferUserTimeZone: boolean
  timeZoneInfo: undefined
}
```

Some values may not be undefined for different users.

This would be the simplest method to retrieve the user full display name, then you may transform for the first name only.

To continue on your example however, this is a simple matter of retrieving the correct entry in `UserProfileProperties` which is an array of `{ Key: string, Value: string ValueType: 'Edm.String' }`. So it would be:

```
const firstNameEntry = userProperties.filter(({ Key }) => Key === "FirstName")[0]
const firstName = firstNameEntry ? firstNameEntry[0].Value : ""
```